# Importing a function into another script Indexing error

Tags: python-3.x, import

I am importing one of my sub functions into my main script and I keep getting the following:

IndexError: list index out of range

I am implementing the same exact function calls in the script as the functions asks for.  Does anyone know a way to check to see if the function is properly imported?

Below is a sample of the code I am working with

```
    from file_with_function import function

    [output1 output2 output3] = function(roll = 15, pitch = 30, 
    yaw = 45)

    print('Argument List: '+ str(sys.argv))
    rolla = int(sys.argv[1])
    pitcha = int(sys.argv[2])
    yawa = int(sys.argv[3])

    def function(roll = 15 , pitch = 30 , yaw = 45):

     #script is here

     if __name__ =='__main__':
            function(
            roll = rolla,
            pitch = pitcha,
            yaw = yawa)
```

Comment: into a script that calls this function

Comment: python3,,,,,,,,

Comment: Just added,,,,,

Comment: William, it would be helpful if you share the script and the file. Thank you.

Comment: Just added some thank you!

Answer (score 0):

There is either an error in the function you're trying to import, or there is something wrong with the data that you are passing into the function. I don't think it's an import error, but without looking at the code I can't really help you.

Comment: Just uploaded some code for more clarification